# Reading large xls files(having 7-8 sheets with each having 30-40,000 rows ) in java

Tags: java, file-io, xls

Is there a way to read large xls files?

I have used Apache POI to read files but only till some limit.

I have a database which has some data and now I want to upload a file of large size (like i told). This file contains little more data in one of its sheets as compare to the data that database has. now how should i update that data in oracle database without setting up the xls file.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/17304/piko
i think u have read a large file and updated the database by using some technique
any help would be highly appreciated......

Comment: Which database? Do you mean that you want to put the file in the db when you say `upload`?

Comment: no @jgauffin i want to read a large file and put some of the content of this file into the oracle databse using sql query 
query part i have done. for small files,i have completed uploading,reading and importing to database.
now how to upload large xls files and read them .............
that is my main concern...... :(

Comment: You are still talking about upload, but you have not mentioned what you are using to upload the files. I don't understand if the problem is with the upload, with the file reading or when analyzing the file. And what error do you get?

Comment: main problem lies with file reading 
still cant get a way to read a large xls file and inserting some of the rows of one of the sheets of this file to oracle database.....
i hope it clears ur doubt..?

Answer (score 2):

For large xls files you should use the streaming extension of XSSF, called [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf). It should be able to handle your requirements without memory problems.

As for the database problem: I'd suggest you read the xls files using XSSF and create temporary tables for each file in the database (depending on your needs). Once all the rows are stored in temp tables you can easily merge them with your existing data.

Comment: Also, i think you can compress it if the file size exceeds in SXSSF. I am not sure if i got the question correctly.. but i think what u are trying to do is save the xls sheet as a BLOB in oracle .. is that so?

Comment: the only thing i want to do is to update only some of the rows from a large xls file to oracle

Comment: then i think @bunting answer is correct. Additionally u can use  the setCompressTempFiles(true) method to zip up the temp files..

Comment: hey buddies, what cud be d problem if i am uploading a large file but action in xhtml page is nt being calld.....
while 4 small file it is being called.

Comment: @bunting : man by using XSSF hw many jar files needed.....
i have downloaded 3 files after facing errors hw many more to download...